# Unwanted variables in Spyder version 4.1.1

Tags: python, spyder

I've downloaded Spyder version 4.1.1. These variables appear every time I open Spyder.

[image: problem here]

I want to delete these variables. I am trying with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> combination, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Aren't those from various libraries? I believe `newaxis` is from NumPy, `e`, `pi` are from math, etc.

Comment: yes, you are right. I solved that problem. Thank u